# Check if post exists

Tags: posts, query

How can I check if post with name for example Weather exists? If not I want to create it.

```
function such_post_exists($title) {
global $wpdb;

$p_title = wp_unslash( sanitize_post_field( 'post_title', $title, 0, 'db' ) );

if ( !empty ( $title ) ) {
    return (int) $wpdb->query("SELECT FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = $p_title");
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wordpress has a `post_exists` function that returns the post ID or 0 otherwise.
So you can do

```
if ( 0 === post_exists( $title ) ) {
    **YOUR_CODE_HERE**
}
```

Comment: What about if I change places : if( 0 == post_exists($post_name) )

Comment: @kilogram It would work both ways

Comment: But that also checks trashed posts?? Any other alternatives.? which can only checks, drafted/publish?

Answer (score 1):

If Post does not exist, create it... IF it does exist, update it.

```php
$post_title = "This Awesome Title";
$post_content = "My content of something cool.";
$post_status = "publish"; //publish, draft, etc
$post_type = "page"; // or whatever post type desired

/* Attempt to find post id by post name if it exists */
$found_post_title = get_page_by_title( $post_title, OBJECT, $post_type );
$found_post_id = $found_post_title->ID;

/**********************************************************
** Check If Page does not exist, if true, create a new post 
************************************************************/
if ( FALSE === get_post_status( $found_post_id ) ): 

      $post_args = array(
        'post_title' => $post_title,
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'post_content'=> $post_content,
        'post_status'  => $post_status,
        //'post_author'  => get_current_user_id(),

        /* If you have meta fields to enter data into */ 
        'meta_input'   => array(
            'meta_key1' => 'my value',
            'meta_key2' => 'my other value',
        ),
      );      


      /* Add a new wp post into db, return it's post id */
      $returned_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_args );  

      /* Update page template only if using "page" as the post_type */ 
      update_post_meta( $returned_post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'my-page-template.php' ); 

      /* Add values into meta fields. Work with ACF CUSTOM FIELDS!! */
      $field_key = "My_Field_KEY";
      $value = "my custom value";
      update_field( $field_key, $value, $returned_post_id );

      $field_key = "My_Other_Field_KEY";
      $value = "my other custom value";
      update_field( $field_key, $value, $returned_post_id );

      /* Save a checkbox or select value */
      // $field_key = "My_Field_KEY";
      // $value = array("red", "blue", "yellow");
      // update_field( $field_key, $value, $returned_post_id );

      /* Save to a repeater field value */
      // $field_key = "My_Field_KEY";
      // $value = array(
      //   array(
      //     "ss_name" => "Foo",
      //     "ss_type" => "Bar"
      //   )
      // );
      // update_field( $field_key, $value, $returned_post_id );

      /* Echo a response! */
      echo "<span class='pg-new'><strong>". $post_title . " Created!</strong></span><br>";
      echo "<a href='".esc_url( get_permalink($returned_post_id) )."' target='_Blank'>". $post_title . "</a><p>";


else:        
/***************************
** IF POST EXISTS, update it 
****************************/

      /* Update post */
      $update_post_args = array(
        'ID'           => $found_post_id,
        'post_title'   => $post_title,
        'post_content' => $post_content,
      );

      /* Update the post into the database */
      wp_update_post( $update_post_args );

      /* Update values into meta fields */
      $field_key = "My_Field_KEY";
      $value = "my custom value";
      update_field( $field_key, $value, $found_post_id );

      $field_key = "My_Other_Field_KEY";
      $value = "my other custom value";
      update_field( $field_key, $value, $found_post_id );

      /* Echo a response! */
      echo "<span class='pg-update'><strong>". $post_title . " Updated!</strong></span><br>"; 
      echo "<a href='".esc_url( get_permalink($found_post_id) )."' target='_Blank'>View</a> | <a href='post.php?post=".$found_post_id."&action=edit'>". $post_title . "</a><p>";

endif;
```